# In Xcode, can you specify another default folder for classes, not Classes/?

Tags: xcode, class, directory

If you create new files, and don't have a Classes/ subdirectory in the project root directory, Xcode dumps them in the project root. I'd like to specify where they go.

FWIW, I know you can link individual files a project to anywhere, with lots of options. Also, what I'm talking about here is the actual file system, not the groups, etc. that you see in your Xcode project.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click (or control-click) on whatever group you want to put the files, and select the option to add a new file.

To put them in a specific location on the file system, select a Location in the drop down menu, or click the Choose button to pick a directory:
[image]

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but thanks anyway. I've reworded the question to try to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: Updated my answer. I guess the short answer is no, you can't pick a *default* directory, but you can specify a location on the file system.